# Full width webpage with gradient

Tags: css, html

I would like to have a background that is an image.  The image must be full width of the browser and fade in from the top and fade out at the bottom using a gradient.  How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` **in combination** with the feature called *multiple background*. You just need to specify the `linear-gradient` as background first (to make it on top) and then specify the image as the second background:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, white), 
              url(http://transviet.com.vn/libs/images/Image/images/San-pham-Tour/Du-lich-trong-nuoc/Mien-Bac/Quang-Ninh/Sightseeing/halong1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/KZd67/8/).
Note that you can change the `white` color to make it fade out in that color. To keep it simple, I just use the `linear-gradient` (which is supported by the current browsers), you can add more browser-specific prefix for older versions.

Comment: Awesome...exactly what I was looking for just one thing though, when I try to load an image from my images folder it doesnt want to load it.  I have a file named bg.jpg and its in the images folder.  My css file is linked correctly because I have a background color showing up.  Is there any kind of problem that could be happening

Comment: @user3457789 I'm not sure, You can try pasting the exact url of that image in the Address bar and see if it shows in the page? That problem means there must be something wrong with the image url, be careful with the relative path. You can also try quoting the path in the `url()` function, some browser may require the url path to be quoted.

Comment: Ok so my path wasnt correct.  But the problem now is the image is shrinking down to the size of the content in the page.  I want it to show on the whole page.

Comment: @user3457789 have you set the style `height:100%` for the `html` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4UJ7d/

Comment: Where is the image? You misderstood what the OP wants, he wants an image to be the background, this image should be faded from top to bottom.